# How to add TextView at the end of a WebView

Tags: android

In my application I need to open a WebView that contains a long html file.

I would like to add a TextView at the end of the WebView, so that only when the user has finished scrolling the WebView, the TextView would show.

I have tried with this Layout, but, no surprise, when I have finished scrolling the WebView the TextView does not show

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try putting them in a scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a `ScrollView` which contains your `LinearLayout`. In you code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```